# Dropdown menus disappear when navbar is fixed on scrolling

Tags: css, navbar

I have a navbar that is a mix of links and dropdowns. When I attempt to make the navbar sticky to the top, so that it will fix to the top of screen as the user scrolls, the dropdown functionality of the navbar quits working.

CSS

```
.topnav {
overflow: hidden;
background-image: url(http://www.buffettworld.com/images/navmenubg.png);
background-size: 100%;
font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
margin-top: 10px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
} 


.topnav a {
float: left;  
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 21px;

}

.topnav .icon {
display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 21px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #b1d235;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">HOME</a>
  <a href="#news">NEWS</a>
  <a href="#news">TOUR</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">JIMMY 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">BIOGRAPHY</a>
        <a href="#">AVIATION</a>
        <a href="#">INCIDENTS</a>
        <a href="#">BUSINESS EMPIRE</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT JIMMY</a>
    </div>
        </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">MUSIC 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">ALBUMS</a>
        <a href="#">SONGS</a>
        <a href="#">CHART HISTORY</a>
        <a href="#">TRIBUTE BANDS</a>
  </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#about">SET LISTS</a>
        <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#about">ADVERTISE</a>
        <a href="#about">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var mytopnav = document.getElementById("mytopnav");
var sticky = mytopnav.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    mytopnav.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    mytopnav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martonian/shopttvk/1/

This is my first time asking a question on here, so hopefully everything is here that is needed. Thanks

Comment: It's the `overflow: hidden;` that hides your dropdown.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!